# Android BLE Receiving only 20Char

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to read 512bytes(Every Seconds) from ble(esp32). But only 20Bytes are receving on my **onCharacteristicChanged** listener. I dont know what do with **gatt.requestMtu(512)**. Tried it also, but no use. any solutions ?

Comment: `requestMTU` allows you to request a larger MTU from the peripheral. The response should contain the MTU that was actually set after your request

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan got it, thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.